# Why doesn't CompletableFuture.complete() throw a ClassCastException when completed with wrong type

Tags: java

This code doesn't print anything, and doesn't throw any error:

```
    CompletableFuture<Integer> publicStage = new CompletableFuture<>();
    publicStage.thenAccept(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i));

    CompletableFuture<String> cfs = (CompletableFuture)publicStage;
    cfs.complete("foo");
```

It's because the function in thenAccept never gets called, I would have expected some sort of error being thrown, instead of it just dropping the function and continuing on.

Comment: Type erasure.  Generics are only a thing at compile time.

Comment: Try to create a [MCVE]. When storing the *actual* `CompletableFuture` that is returned by the `thenAccept` call, and then trying to call `get` on this future, a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks, that helped me wrap my head around how I used it wrong.